# Is it okay to make small edits to meta posts to change my vote?

Tags: discussion, edits, voting, meta, per-site-meta

If I see a meta answer that I voted on a long time ago, but I now have a different opinion on the topic and want to change my vote, is it okay to make a minor edit to the post so I can change my vote?

Comment: Does it matter that it was a long time ago? If you think it's OK to make a trivial edit so you can bypass the mechanism that prevents you from changing your vote, why would it matter that it was a long time ago, or 15 minutes ago?

Comment: @ColleenV It does matters that it was a long time ago, because in that time your view on a certain matter can legitimately change quite a lot (not just on a whim).

Comment: @ElementsInSpace OK, so how many minutes have to pass before its long enough for you to feel that its OK to break the rules on a trivial edit? Is it different for different people? My point being, we change our minds all the time for perfectly valid reasons. We don't have to go back and update all our votes just because we changed our mind.

Comment: @ColleenV I don’t know what a reasonable amount of time is (perhaps a month?).  If I’ve learnt something, I’d like my votes to reflect my current view.  Having to “break the rules” to do this is a sign that the rules aren’t ideal.

Comment: The Meta sites (and meta sites in general) are used differently from the "main" sites. Since the rules have been created for the latter, I think the possibility of being able to change votes is a very good idea (but agree that minor edits are not the right way). Perhaps not locking in votes on meta sites is a good alternative?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [help center page on editing:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/editing)

> Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged; try to make the post significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you observe.

Making a minor edit *just* so you can change your vote doesn't sound like the kind of edit that would make the post better, or would even correct all problems. So don't do it.

Answer (score 7):

Frame challenge: if you voted on a meta answer a *long* time ago, and now disagree with your vote, circumstances have probably changed. In which case, it might be worth asking a new question, to solicit up-to-date opinions on the topic.

Comment: +1, but the problem could then shift to your new question being regarded as a duplicate, and it ultimately not being worth the effort.